# Change help expressions in Properties View in Sirius Diagram

Tags: eclipse-emf, emf, eclipse-emf-ecore, eclipse-sirius

I have two questions:

1. How can I change the help expressions in the Sirius Diagram? (See attached image.) I want to change the help expressions associated with the (?) symbol. I do not want to create my own properties view as explained in [this](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Sirius/Tutorials/PropertiesViewTutorial) tutorial. neither I want to extend the default one. Where is it reading this description from?
2. The radio buttons on the main page of the default properties view can not be changed. They are in the read-only mode. However, I am able to change them from the semantic page. Is it a bug? (see attached image.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Regarding question 1, I believe you need a widget override, as described here:
[Properties_View_Description.html](https://www.eclipse.org/sirius/doc/specifier/properties/Properties_View_Description.html#overrides).

Override gives you the ability to specify your own Label, Help, Is Enabled and Value Expressions:
[image]